# Can't use strava API in C#

Tags: c#, strava

From strava reference https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Clubs-getClubMembersById
I'm trying to use strava API in C#.
I installed Strava.NET v3.4.4 on Concole App (.NET Framework 4.6.1 on Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019) as picture below.
[image: Install Strava.NET v3.4.4]

I just added strava reference as the link above.
Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using com.strava.api.v3.Api;
using com.strava.api.v3.Client;
using com.strava.api.v3.Model;

namespace getClubMembersById
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
The type or namespace name 'com' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

[image: The type or namespace name 'com' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)]

Comment: Could you check `Target framework` in your project properties?

Comment: Where did you find `com.strava.api.v3.Api` ? That looks like a Java namespace. .NET namespaces are Pascal-cased and don't include domains. I'd expect the namespace to start with `Strava`-something

Comment: @Rob, .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, OK, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Strava C# example is generic so you have to read `Strava.NET` library documentation.

`Strava.NET` includes these namespaces.

[image]

Please note that `Strava.NET 3.4.4` was last updated on `02/04/2016` but Strava introduced [important updates since `15/10/2018`](https://developers.strava.com/docs/oauth-updates/).